# Utility to fix Python import style?

Tags: python, coding-style

We have a lot of files with ugly import statements like this:

```
from project.foo import a, b
from project.foo import c
from project.bar import d, e, f, g
```

Does there exist something that will change them all to one import per line?

```
from project.foo import a
from project.foo import b
from project.foo import c
from project.bar import d
from project.bar import e
from project.bar import f
from project.bar import g
```

**Clarification:** The reason for this is to maintain a consistent style, like [Google's style guide for Python](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#Imports_formatting).

Comment: why would you want one import per line?

Comment: Don't bring java habits to Python

Comment: I agree with JBernardo. I do java at work and I hate this. Unnecessary junk.

Comment: I appreciate all the sentiment. You have convinced me! However, I'll leave this question in the case that someone really wants to do what I asked.

Comment: I would be more useful to have a utility that fixes `from foo import *` to `from foo import a, b`.

Answer (score 7):

As per [PEP8 style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Imports
>
> ```
> - Imports should usually be on separate lines, e.g.:
>
>     Yes: import os
>          import sys
>
>     No:  import sys, os
>
>   it's okay to say this though:
>
>     from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
> ```

So, I think you should be doing what you are and should not split them. I am not aware of any utility which will do that for you.

Also, if:

`project.bar` contains say: `d,e,f,g,x,y,z` then I would say just do a `import project.bar`, code will be much less and easy for the eyes.

Comment: As a note, I would recommend the OP to import `project.bar` with `import project.bar as bar` and use `bar.d`, `bar.e` etc.

Answer (score 0):

sed can do that with something like this (test first as I don't have access to my Linux box to test it at the moment):

```
sed -i".backup" 's/from ([^ ]+) import ([^,]+), ([^,]+)/from \1 import \2\nfrom \1 import \3/' *.py
```

Comment: Hmm: `sed: -e expression #1, char 76: invalid reference \3 on `s' command's RHS`